# Animate and image up and down in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to animate and image up and then down with jQuery.

It should behave like this:

When the page loads it shows 50% of the image. If someone clicks on the image it then animates the div up the page. If the user click again it moves back down the page.

html

```
 <div id="slidebottom" class="slide">
     <div class="inner"><img src="images/sze.jpg" alt="" class="try" /></div>
 </div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.try').click(function() {
        $(".inner").animate({
            top: '-=100px'
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

How can I reverse the animation after click two? At the moment every time I click, the container moves up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the `.toggle()` method, which takes two functions and alternates between executing each one of them on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.try').toggle(function() {
    $(".inner").animate({top: '-=100px'}, 2000);
  }, function() {
    $(".inner").animate({top: '+=100px'}, 2000);
  });
});
```

However, I personally would use a class and CSS3 Transitions.

Comment: It is possible to not work in Chrome the animate? FF work this, but in Chrome after click the image first the image jump down, and animate up, if i click again than animate the hole site..crazy effect

Comment: i tried in Chrome , IE9, Safari...only FF handle it as ascpected.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/menislici/jGfHM/). Also note that in order to use the `top` css property you should either `position: relatve;` or `position: absolute` the `.inner` div.

```
 var clicked = false
 $('.try').click(function () {
     if (clicked == true) {
         $(".inner").animate({
             top: '0px'
         }, 2000);
         clicked = false;
     } else {
         $(".inner").animate({
             top: '-100px'
         }, 2000);
         clicked = true;
     }
 });​
```

Comment: 90% of the examples wouldn't for me, but this one does…

Answer (score 0):

Just put another code line underneath the first and it will animate them in order

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.try').click(function() {
        $(".inner").animate({
            top: '-=100px'
        }, 2000);
        $(".inner").animate({
            top: '+=100px'
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```